# Trying to use source routing on two different interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have defined the following rules:

```
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source [publicip]
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -d 192.168.0.0/24 --to-source 192.168.0.6
```

Basically, I want only the private network to go through 192.168.0.6.  However, only one network works.  With this config, only the public network works.  Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables rules need to be configured in order of more-specific rules before less-specific.

The right order should be:

```
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -d 192.168.0.0/24 --to-source 192.168.0.6
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source [publicip]
```

The [Wikipedia article about iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) explains both this and the flow of packets through chains and tables rather well.

> The packet continues to traverse the chain until either:
>   1. a rule matches the packet and decides the ultimate fate of the packet, for example by calling one of the ACCEPT or DROP, or a module returning such an ultimate fate [...]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue. Order matters apparently. Setting the private network first appears to fix the problem. I also added 0.0.0.0/0, pretty sure this is the default so I don't think that changed anything but I'm not testing to find out.

```
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -d 192.168.0.0/24 --to-source 192.168.0.6
-A POSTROUTING -j SNAT -d 0.0.0.0/0 --to-source [publicip]
```

Comment: In your case obviously order matters as the publicip rule matches all traffic, so if you put it first it will match all not allowing any to reach the second rule. You do not have to explicitly put -d 0.0.0.0/0.